# EntityFramework - SaveChanges not saving but SQL seen in Profiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-4.3

I have read through most every post on EF-SaveChanges and do not believe my answer lies in any of those posts.

I am using C#, .NET 4, EF 4.3.1, SQL Server 2008R2, VS 2k11 Beta, AutoMapper.

Here is my code:

```
using (Model.AnimalRescueEntities context = new Model.AnimalRescueEntities())
{
    using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        context.Connection.Open();

        //Retrieve the event
        eventDB = context.Events.Single(e => e.ID == eventRegVM.EventID);
        eventOrgBaseDB = context.Entity_Base.Single(b => b.ID == eventDB.Entity_Organisation.ID);
        eventRegVM.Event = Mapper.Map<Model.Event, EventsViewModel>(eventDB);
        eventRegVM.Event.Entity_Organisation.Entity_Base = Mapper.Map<Model.Entity_Base, Entity_BaseViewModel>(eventOrgBaseDB);

        //saves Event_Registration
        eventRegDB = Mapper.Map<Event_RegistrationViewModel, Model.Event_Registration>(eventRegVM);
        eventRegDB.Event = eventDB;
        eventRegDB.EventID = eventDB.ID;
        eventRegDB.Event.Entity_Organisation = context.Entity_Organisation.Single(o => o.ID == eventOrgBaseDB.ID);
        eventRegDB.Event.Entity_Organisation.Entity_Base = eventOrgBaseDB;

        //Add the link between EVENT and REGISTRATION
        context.Event_Registration.AddObject(eventRegDB);
        int numChanges = context.SaveChanges();

        var regs = context.Event_Registration.Where(r => r.ID != null).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have SQL Profiler running in the background and when SaveChanges is called I see this SQL code (**numChanges** is 1):

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @generated_keys table([ID] uniqueidentifier)
insert [dbo].[Event_Registration]([EventID], [DateSubmitted], [HasPaid], [PaymentMethod], [Comments], [AmountPaid])
output inserted.[ID] into @generated_keys
values (@0, @1, null, @2, null, @3)
select t.[ID]
from @generated_keys as g join [dbo].[Event_Registration] as t on g.[ID] = t.[ID]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 datetime2(7),@2 int,@3 decimal(19,4)',@0='1D841F75-AEA1-4ED1-B3F0-4E3994D7FC0D',@1='2012-07-04 14:59:45.5239309',@2=0,@3=0
```

**regs** will contain three exist rows and my new row. However, I cannot run a SELECT statement in SQL Server and see my new row. Running this many times will get me the same result - three existing rows in the database and a new fourth row that will never make it to the database.

**eventRegDB** also contains the GUID created for the primary key, ID; I assume SQL server does this but not 100% sure of that.

I have taken the above TSQL and run it in a query window against my database - I get new rows in my Event_Registration table after that - that is how the three existing rows were created.

I see now exceptions or other errors generated and cannot find any reason this would not save to the database. Any ideas? If you want to see the schema for the SQL, how to recreate the database, the code (any or all), then ask - this is all hosted on http://animalrescue.codeplex.com/ but I haven't stored this code, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `transaction.Complete()` so your transaction is never committed. When the `using` block for `TransactionScope` completes your transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Thank you Mmka. Glad it was a simple thing that I missed!